# ActiveRecord AssociationType Mismatch

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I have a Rails 3.2.21 app where I'm adding a simple form/collection_select field in my form.  When selecting an object from the dropdown (or leaving it blank) I get the following error:

```
ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch at /calls/5
BillFacility(#70179530126460) expected, got String(#70179505820040)
```

Here's what my models look like:

**call.rb**

```
belongs_to :bill_facility
attr_accessible :bill_facility_id
```

**bill_facility.rb**

```
has_many :calls
```

Here's what my form looks like:

**_form.html.erb**

```
<%= f.collection_select(:bill_facility_id, BillFacility.order("facility_name ASC"), :id, :facility_name, {:include_blank => true}, {:class => 'select'}) %>
```

Here's the migrations I did to add the `BillFacility` model and add the `bill_facility_id` to the `Call` model:

```
class CreateBillFacilities < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :bill_facilities do |t|
      t.string :facility_name
      t.string :facility_address

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end

class AddBillFaciltyIdToCalls < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :calls, :bill_facility_id, :integer
  end
end
```

If I manually assign the call an id in `bill_facility_id` I get an unknown `to_i` method error.  If I manually make it nil then select a `BillFacilty` from the drop down (or leave it blank) I get the mismatch error:

```
ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch at /calls/5
BillFacility(#70179530126460) expected, got String(#70179505820040)
```

I'm sure this is something simple that I'm missing.  Anyone have any ideas on what I'm doing wrong here?  It's a bit early so my mind is kind of fuzzy so I should probably wait until I'm fully awake but figured I'd ask for some help.

If you have any questions, please let me know.

Comment: Please add the full backtrace as well as the controller code.

Answer (score 0):

I think I have this figured out.  Definitely not awake enough to be writing code.

I had this in my form before the `BillFacility` collection_select

```
<%= f.label :Bill_Facility, "Bill Facility", class: "control-label" %><%= f.check_box :bill_facility, :id => 'bill_facility_checkbox' %>
```

So I was calling a field named `bill_facility` that was in my database, but since `bill_facility` is an associated model, it gave me the mismatch error.  So I simple altered the migration to change the check_box to `bill_fac` and it worked.